# Why aren't memory leaks fixed when the leaking process is terminated?

Tags: memory-leaks

As far as I know, memory leaks (`malloc` without `free` in C) persist even after the process which leaked is terminated, causing the whole machine to be starved of memory and  slow down over time.

Why doesn't the OS simply deallocate all the allocated memory of a process upon termination?

Comment: they may be shared objects that exist outside the processes virtual address space. in that case, unless the objects are associated with a managed runtime that can perform garbage collection, the OS cannot tell if the object is still in use by other processes, and will not de-allocate the object. for private in-proc memory, it behaves as you suggest, and no longer tracks those physical addresses as in-use.

Comment: @Ramhound: That's not true for any modern OS. Each application has *its own* address space, each application has to use OS calls to map/unmap stuff to it, so the OS knows exactly what memory each application has mapped and is able to destroy all of it in the end. It might not have been the case for MS-DOS or Win98, but it is the case for WinNT or Linux or OSX. The only leaks that could remain are either shared objects that something else has a ref to, or kernel memory leaks (like bad drivers).